# Git repo structure with multiple docker files

Tags: node.js, git, nginx, redis, docker

What is the best way to structure a repository / project that has multiple `Dockerfile` for provisioning services.

e.g.

`Dockerfile` # build Nodejs app server

`Dockerfile` # build Nginx forward proxy

`Dockerfile` # build Redis cache server

What is the **best practices** and **standard** structure within a repository to contain this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generally have one folder per Dockerfile, as:

- each one can use multiple other resource files (config files, data files, ...) when doing their respective `docker build -t xxx .`
- each one can have its own `.dockerignore`

My [project `b2d`](https://github.com/VonC/b2d), for instance, has one Dockerfile per application:

[image: Dockerfiles]

Comment: would it be possible and sensible to have: /docker, /docker/node/Dockerfile, /docker/nginx/Dockerfile....

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan As long as you keep your Dockerfile in their own folders, organizing them by type of apps makes sense, yes.

Comment: Can you update your answer to have an example repo folder structure? just for future reference.

Comment: Wait wait... so basically you are saying have a SEPERATE repo for my docker infrastructure provisioning?

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan you have just one repo, with multiple folders in it. Is that a problem?

Comment: actually I have this within the repository for the application, not a seperate "devops" repo.

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan That should not be an issue then.